# In browsers that support HTML5, how is the same origin policy handled with respect to key-value database on the local filesystem?

Tags: html, security, same-origin-policy, key-value-store

I have a webapp that has, as a major attraction, that it handles partial personal information management out of a key-value store. It works at a basic level when accessed from my website; I would like to know how well it works or doesn't work packaged as a downloadable zipfile, saved page, etc., and if there is anything I can do to let it work better when run as a local file instead of downloaded from a browser.

How do the browsers' key-value stores handle the origin being a point on the local filesystem?